# Help in understanding the algebra of hadamard test

Tags: linear-algebra, hadamard, hadamard-test

I am new to quantum computing and was looking through the jupyter notebook of Variational Quantum Linear Solver by Qiskit. I came across the hadamard test and was not understanding how it works.
It is written there,

Circuit:
[[Hadamard test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as65Q.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as65Q.png)

$$\frac{|0\rangle \ + \ |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \ \otimes \ |\psi\rangle \ = \ \frac{|0\rangle \ \otimes \ |\psi\rangle \ + \ |1\rangle \ \otimes \ |\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Applying our controlled unitary:

$$\frac{|0\rangle \ \otimes \ |\psi\rangle \ + \ |1\rangle \ \otimes \ |\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \ \rightarrow \ \frac{|0\rangle \ \otimes \ |\psi\rangle \ + \ |1\rangle \ \otimes \ U|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Then applying the Hadamard gate to the first qubit:

$$\frac{|0\rangle \ \otimes \ |\psi\rangle \ + \ |1\rangle \ \otimes \ U|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \ \rightarrow \ \frac{1}{2} \ \big[ |0\rangle \ \otimes \ |\psi\rangle \ + \ |1\rangle \ \otimes \ |\psi\rangle \ + \ |0\rangle \ \otimes \ U|\psi\rangle \ - \ |1\rangle \ \otimes \ U|\psi\rangle \big]$$

$$\Rightarrow \ \frac{1}{2} |0\rangle \ \otimes \ (\mathbb{I} \ + \ U)|\psi\rangle \ + \ \frac{1}{2} |1\rangle \ \otimes \ (\mathbb{I} \ - \ U)|\psi\rangle$$

How do we get the equation "applying hadamard gate to the first qubit"? Especially the fourth term which is negative.

[Link to the notebook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-paper-implementations/vqls.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hadamard gate $H$ transforms the computational basis as follows: $$\begin{align}H\lvert 0\rangle &= \lvert + \rangle = \frac{\lvert 0\rangle + \lvert 1\rangle}{\sqrt 2} \\ H\lvert 1\rangle &= \lvert - \rangle = \frac{\lvert 0\rangle \color{red}- \lvert 1\rangle}{\sqrt 2}\end{align}$$ So, to elaborate a little bit on the steps involved  in the transformation that's confusing you: applying a Hadamard gate to the first qubit equates to applying $H\otimes I$ to the whole system, which gives us the result
$$\begin{align*}
(H\otimes I)\bigg(\frac{\lvert 0\rangle\otimes\lvert\psi\rangle + \lvert 1\rangle\otimes U\lvert\psi\rangle}{\sqrt 2}\bigg)
&= \frac{H\lvert 0\rangle\otimes\lvert\psi\rangle + H\lvert 1\rangle\otimes U\lvert\psi\rangle}{\sqrt 2} \\
&= \frac{\tfrac{\lvert 0\rangle + \lvert 1\rangle}{\sqrt 2}\otimes \lvert\psi\rangle + \tfrac{\lvert 0\rangle \color{red}- \lvert 1\rangle}{\sqrt 2}\otimes U\lvert\psi\rangle}{\sqrt 2} \\
&= \frac{\lvert 0\rangle\otimes\lvert\psi\rangle + \lvert 1\rangle\otimes\lvert\psi\rangle + \lvert 0\rangle\otimes U\lvert\psi\rangle \color{red}- \lvert 1\rangle\otimes U\lvert\psi\rangle}{2}
\end{align*}$$
Does this clear up where the sign of the fourth term comes from?

Comment: Yes, That makes sense. I didn't take into account how Hadamard acts on $|1\rangle$ state.  Thank you.